# Artistic writing

Tags: single-word-requests

Let's say I divide all writing activities in two classes:

1. Artistic writing
2. Non-artistic writing

Artistic writing includes fiction and non-fiction. Its purpose is either to entertain the reader (fiction) or tell them something they don't know (non-fiction).

Non-artistic writing includes writing e-mails, newsletters, blog posts, white papers, landing pages, social media content etc. The purpose of non-artistic writing is to sell something to the reader, either now or later, either to them personally or to someone they influence.

I consider it non-artistic because it is order of magnitudes easier to write a good, say, white paper than a good fiction or non-fiction book (there is much more good copywriters than there are good fiction and non-fiction writers).

**What is a better (shorter) word than "artistic writing" that can be used for both fiction and non-fiction?**

Possible answer: *Journalism and fiction writing*

But it's even longer than the term I want to get rid of.

Example of using the sought expression in a sentence:

> Before F. Scott Fitzgerald, Joseph Heller, and Steven Pressfield became masters of `<blank>` they used to work as copywriters.

`<Blank>` -- better word for "artistic writing".

Comment: The common term is *creative writing*. And I think you undervalue and underestimate the other kind.

Comment: @DanBron It sounds like OP is including journalism in their 'artistic writing' category, which is usually not in scope for 'creative writing', as I understand it.

Comment: I realize you wanted to be more specific, but simply saying 'masters of writing' would seem to work well in that sentence. I don't think any reader will suspect that you mean they are good at drafting social media copy. The word 'wordcraft' might also apply.

Comment: Literary writing covers some journalism  as well as fiction and poetry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Merriam-Webster, the definition of [**literature**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/literature) includes all of these senses:

> **1 a (1)** : writings in prose or verse
>   *especially* : writings having excellence of form or expression and expressing ideas of permanent or universal interest
>   // *literature* stands related to man as science stands to nature
>   — J. H. Newman
>   **1 a (2)** : an example of such writings
>   // what came out, though rarely *literature*, was always a roaring good story
>   — *People*
>   **1 b** : the body of writings on a particular subject
>   // scientific *literature*
>   **1 c** : the body of written works produced in a particular language, country, or age
>   // French *literature*
>   // Renaissance *literature*
>   **1 d** : printed matter (such as leaflets or circulars)
>   // campaign *literature*
>   **2** : the production of literary work especially as an occupation
>   // *Literature* is his profession.

The fact that the definition includes "printed matter (such as leaflets or circulars)," means that it can also cover "e-mails, newsletters, blog posts, white papers, landing pages, social media content etc."

As such:

> Before F. Scott Fitzgerald, Joseph Heller, and Steven Pressfield became masters of *literature* they used to work as copywriters.